# How to read an input then write on same line?

Tags: vb.net, readline

I'm working on Visual Basic and would like to ask how can I input in this format?
"First name: Abdul, Second name: Sharif"

I wrote this code:

```
    Console.Write("First name: ")
    FirstName = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Write(", Second name: ")
    SecondName = Console.ReadLine()
```

However, after I input the first value, it jumps to next line. 
So what is the way to input and write on the same line?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `Console.Write()` and `Console.WriteLine()`, the `Console.Read()` method DOESN'T do the same as it's counterpart, `Console.ReadLine()` without going down a line. Instead, it reads the next character. `Console.Read()` and `Console.ReadKey()` can be used to achieve what you want,
But there's another approach that I find better suiting your need;
Subtract 1 from the `Console.CursorTop` variable, and then set the `Console.CursorLeft` variable to the position (in the X axis) you want to print to.
Then, print the string. When changing the cursor's X position, remember to take in mind the length of the input as it is echoed, as well as any characters in the previous line in general.

One might say that `Console.SetCursorPosition()` can be used here and that's currect, but it is less efficient, as you will need to get the current Y position of the cursor + call a method.

Answer (score 0):

ReadLine() reads a line, this is why it goes to the next line.

You need to use ReadKey() instead.  But then you will need a loop to add it to the FirstName variable and you will have to process special characters (like Enter/Return).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! It works now.

```
    Console.Write("First name: ")
    FirstName = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.CursorTop = Console.CursorTop - 1
    Console.SetCursorPosition(Len("First name; " & FirstName), Console.CursorTop)
    Console.Write(", Second name: ")
    SecondName = Console.ReadLine()
```